# The code format is cutted off on blogger mobile view without a scrolling bar option

Tags: html, blogger

The code format is cutted off on blogger mobile view without a scrolling bar option. 
This is my blog post with this inconvenient:
[My blog post](https://www.linuxtechmore.com/2020/05/top-things-to-do-after-installing-solus.html?m=1)

Comment: Hello, 
One solution i've been thinking about would be to use media queries. I saw that you used a margin-left on the parent div of the code element, maybe you can scale it to the mobile viewport using a media querie?
Is this solutions relevant for you?

Comment: @Djalel, Better you post a screenshot of the screen, for better understanding, and quicker solution.

Comment: @JeuneApprenti, I will try that out, but any more details will be helpful.

Comment: @Allahbakash.G, currently as a new user, I can't add pictures.